# Printing floating-point numbers (hexadecimal) in IEEE standard in C

Tags: c, floating-point, 32-bit, ieee-754

I want to print the hexadecimal value of two floating point numbers in the IEEE standard representation (sign, 8 bit exponent, 23 bit mantissa). My problem is that the numbers that I random generate are super big (for example: -26815622280406798000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000) without any numbers after the point (only 0) and with sign.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>

float RandVectorGen(void);

int main () {

    srand(time(NULL));

    float Vectors_A = 0, Vectors_B = 0, Vectors_SUM = 0; 

            for(int i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
                
                Vectors_A = RandVectorGen();      //Genera 20 vettori tra 100 e 0
                Vectors_B = RandVectorGen();

                printf("Vettore %d_A: %x  =>  %.6f\n", i, Vectors_A, Vectors_A);
                printf("Vettore %d_B: %x  =>  %.6f\n", i, Vectors_B, Vectors_B);

                Vectors_SUM = Vectors_A + Vectors_B;            

                printf("Somma tra i due vettori: %x  =>  %.6f\n", Vectors_SUM, Vectors_SUM);

                puts(" ");

                }

    return 0;

}

float RandVectorGen (void) {

    
    unsigned int Vector1, Vector2;
    float RandomVector = ((float)Vector1 / (float)Vector2) * fabs(sin(rand() % 10));

        Vector1 = (rand() % 30);
        Vector2 = (rand() % 30);

    return RandomVector;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "dump the raw form of the floating-point value as hexadecimal" or do you mean "dump the hexadecimal equivalent value"?

Comment: Note, the indentation style used here is really chaotic and hard to follow.

Comment: Yes i would like to print the raw form of floating-point like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/IEEE_754_Single_Floating_Point_Format.svg/618px-IEEE_754_Single_Floating_Point_Format.svg.png

Comment: You need to recast as an unsigned int of a matching size, then dump that. `float` maps to `uint32_t` usually, and `double` to `uint64_t`, but do double-check that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Comment: You can use the `%a` or `%A` printf format specifier to print a floating point value in hexadecimal.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah now it work but i'm not sure thats is the IEEE F-P rapresentation: 

I get this output:

Vettore 0_A: 0X1.50608CP-2  =>  0.328493
Vettore 0_B: 0X0.000000P+0  =>  0.000000
Somma tra i due vettori: 0X1.50608CP-2  =>  0.328493 (don't know what's P-2 tho)

Which is ok but when i convert 0.328493 in IEEE rapresentation i get: 0x3ea8303c

Comment: @Gabbed The P-2 is the exponent part as a power of 2, which gets printed in decimal. The printed value is a representation of the binary floating point format, but is not the "raw" representation that results from reading the `float` as `uint32_t`.

Comment: A common trick used to reinterpret the binary representation of a type as a different type (known as "type punning") is to use a union. For example `union foo { float f; unsigned int ui; };` `union foo x;` x.f = Vectors_A;` `printf("%x", x.ui);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott oh ok so i  have to change the approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of flow control, C runs from top to bottom. So when you initialize `RandomVector` using two uninitialized variables, you get Undefined Behavior. It does not matter that you later assign two values to `Vector`1 and `Vector2`.

Comment: In other words, "initialize your values *before* using them".

Comment: I corrected but I always get the same results

Comment: @Gabbed: You probably should learn to use the debugger on your system.

Comment: "I always get the same results". So, a different problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RandomVector` is random in the sense that it is based on uninitialized values, which is undefined behavior. You only assign values to `Vector1` and `Vector2` after that, but you never use those. You should try it like this:

```
float RandVectorGen (void)
{
    unsigned int Vector1, Vector2;
    float RandomVector;

    Vector1 = (rand() % 30);
    Vector2 = (rand() % 30);
    
    RandomVector = ((float)Vector1 / (float)Vector2) * fabs(sin(rand() % 10));

    return RandomVector;
}
```

Comment: Still getting these super big number. This is an example of the output:

Vettore 3_A: 40000000  =>  2.000000
Vettore 3_B: 60000000  =>  26815622242753719000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
Somma tra i due vettori: 0  =>  0.000000      (Sum)

Comment: @Gabbed. Use a debugger. When I run your code with just that function replaced by mine, I get results like this: Vettore 20_A: 20000000  =>  0.075988
Vettore 20_B: 60000000  =>  0.154560
Somma tra i due vettori: fbadd2a0  =>  0.230548

Comment: There is a 1 in 30 chance of getting a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: @IanAbbott No, they are floats. They don't cause a divide-by-zero error. There's a chance of getting `inf` for a result though.

Comment: @Gabbed The '%x' format specifier expects an `unsigned int` as argument, but you're passing a `float`. If those types are of different size, `printf` may corrupt your stack, and that can have some weird side effects like the printing of garbage data.